# call global object in the main app.js from seperate file private function

Tags: javascript, object

i built an app on 1 page, and now i want to oragenize all of its functions and objects in seperate files and directories, and import them to the app.js file. but im having some problems with global objects, the the imported functions dosent recognize them.

example:

```
    //app.js 
     const req_obj = require("./objectFile.js")

     const tool = {
       number:4   
     } 
     req_obj.obj.addFive() // this will print "cant read number of undefined" 



   //objectFile.js
     const req_func = require("./function.js") 

     exports.obj = {
       addFive:req_func.addFive
     }



  //function.js

    exports.addFive = function(){
       return tool.number + 5
     }
```

i know that it might be that im doing all wrong, and this is not how you orgenize an app and call its function. i whould be really glad if some1 will explaine my how to orgenize an app, and call its functions the right way, if what i did is wrong.

Comment: What environment are you working in, the browser, node or something else? What module loader are you using?

Comment: If you using modules,  `tool` is not a global.

Comment: Hint: Unlike `function.js`, the `objectFile.js` module doesn't export anything.

Comment: im using chrome enviroment,  in using webpack binder. and babel syntax
the tool is not exported beacuse its on the main app.js that i run the code from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility you have to get access to variables from multiple files is to have them in a separate file and export them like this:

```
// objects.js
const tool = {
    number:4
}

exports.tool = tool
```

Which then makes your `app.js` look like:

```
//app.js 
const req_obj = require("./objectFile.js")
const tool = require("./objects.js").tool

 // this will read 9
console.log(req_obj.obj.addFive())
```

And your `function.js` then becomes:

```
const tool = require("./objects.js").tool

exports.addFive = function(){
    return tool.number + 5
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes you right its indeed work this way i already know, and yes i forgot to write export.obj wich i did in my privat code the problam im facing is how to call a global object from inside imported function without passing it as an argument if its possible

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, let me update my answer then.

Comment: You really should pass it as an argument though. You need very good reasons to make it a global static variable.

Comment: My original answer was to pass it as a variable but since it seems to be a specific need for a global variable I updated my answer to help in that direction.